# Problems setting iframe size

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've tried lots of ways of setting the `iframe` size in [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) 2.1.5, mostly ideas taken from other questions on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work. Instead, on clicking links (which are dynamically generated), an `iframe` opens very small (`300 x 150px`). I can see that `.fancybox-inner` has the correct width and height, but the actual iframe has no no width/height attributes. The target of the link is always a PDF, not an HTML page.

Here is my code:

```
$(".homebox a.fancybox").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
         $.fancybox({
            href: $(this).attr('href'),
            fitToView: false,
            autoSize: false,
            autoDimensions: false,
            width  : 600,
            height : 900,
            type   :'iframe'
         });
         e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Any ideas much appreciated. (NB. I use `e.stopPropagation()` because the `a.fancybox` link is actually a child of another link.)

Comment: I usually also set the `minWidth` and `maxWidth` to the same

Comment: Thanks Pete -- just tried it but no joy.

Comment: have you tried setting the dimensions of the body on your opened document to have a min width and height of 600x900? or made sure there is a style in your css for 
`.fancybox-iframe { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

Comment: That css is there. I have no control over the document, but I should have said that the target of these links is always a PDF, not an HTML page. I'll update my question to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that fancybox calculates the size before the iframe content is completely loaded hence the small size.

Try adding the iframe `preload` set to `false` in your script like :

```
$(".fancybox").on("click", function (e) {
    $.fancybox({
        href: this.href,
        fitToView: false,
        autoSize: false,
        // autoDimensions: false, // this is for fancybox v1.3.x
        width: 600,
        height: 900,
        type: 'iframe',
        iframe: {
            preload: false
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ec3d9/)**

PS. I wouldn't recommend to nest links inside other links. There will be always better design options to workaround your needs. My 5¢

Comment: Thanks JFK -- but I had already seen the `preload:false` advice elsewhere (perhaps from you!) and tried it out, no joy. In the end I decided to go with another lightbox which worked fine.